# Method with boolean return - if else vs. if

Tags: methods, boolean, return, if-statement

Take for example the following two statements:

```
if (booleanVariable)
{
  doSomething();

  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

and

```
if (booleanVariable)
{
  doSomething();

  return true;
}

return false;
```

Which one would be preferred?

They both return the same result in the end.

Any reason one would be better to use than the other?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677843/is-there-any-appreciable-difference-between-if-and-if-else

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "else" rarely used after "if x then return"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261849/why-is-else-rarely-used-after-if-x-then-return)

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I think the cleanest way would be

```
if (booleanVariable) {
    doSomething();
}
return booleanVariable;
```

Moving the redundant returns outside the if block highlights what you are doing differently if the variable is set.

Comment: Or, whenever booleanVariable is set to true (probably defaulted as false), immediately call doSomething(). Either way, it's less code.

Answer (score 0):

The if...else structure provides more readable code, but if you understand it fine and don't want to write as much, just do the second one :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it in different way. since, your first code solution might give an error, at least in c# since you will need to return a value outside of if-else scope.

i would have created a separate bool variable, and set it to true/false depending on what your if-test results

```
bool test;

if (booleanVariable)
{
  doSomething();

  test = true;
}

return test;
```

now if the if-test fail, the return bool will stay false as default.